# Sed insert right after <body...>

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to add line of html right after the opening `<body...>` tag, however there aren't any newlines, so it makes it somewhat difficult for me.

For example, I want to insert `<p>This is the first line</p>`, which I call from a text file, after `<body...>` tag:

`<html><head><title>Some title</title></head><body style="word-wrap: break-word; -webkit-nbsp-mode: space; -webkit-line-break: after-white-space; ">Some text goes here`

Everything I've tried so far only inserts after the first newline of the matched string. How can I insert after body when the body styling is always different?

Comment: `s/(<body[^>]*>)/\1newtexthere/`.  The most important piece is the `[^>]*>` bit, of course.

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not advisable to manipulate HTML with sed. However you can try:

```
sed -i.bak 's~<body[^>]*>~&<p>This is the first line</p>~' file.html
```

Comment: Thank you, it works.
I am interested to know though, how does this part work:
`[^>]`

Comment: The expression `[^>]*` means zero or more characters which are _not_ `>`. This means absorb anything up to but not including the closing `>`.